# Why does random.uniform(0, float("inf")) always return inf?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I was playing around with the `random` module in python and I found that this code always returns `inf`:

```py
import random

print(random.uniform(0, float("inf")))
```

I was wondering why and if there is another way of doing this so that it does not always return `inf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you investigate `random.uniform` source it will be clear:

```
def uniform(self, a, b):
    "Get a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding."
    return a + (b-a) * self.random()
```

Any arithmetic with `float('inf')` returns `-inf` or `inf`.

In this case:

`b-a` where `b` is `inf` evaluates to `inf`, `inf * self.random()` is `inf` (or `-inf` if `self.random()` is negative) and `a + inf` is `inf`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure why you would want a random number in an unspecified range, but maybe for practical purposes using something like `sys.maxsize` as the upper bound could be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Picking a value uniformly at random in an infinite range is equivalent to picking an element uniformly at random from an infinite set. Uniform means that all your elements have the same probability `p` of being selected. If `p` is positive, then the sum of the probabilities in your distribution is equal to `p*inf`, which is infinite, and therefore not equal to 1.

As it as been mentioned in the accepted answer, reading the code explains why this particular implementation returns `inf` but this is not a bug, that's the only logical thing this function call could return. But in my opinion this should just raise an error.

Note that you may interpret random float generation (in any interval) to be equivalent to picking an element from an infinite set, but that's not the case because we are not using infinite precision float numbers (they are not real numbers). This is what makes a call to `random.uniform(0, 1)` well defined.